# How to get different string from a file in xcode 4?

Tags: xcode4

In my prgram, I want to use a txt file to store all the words that I need to use.  Here is the example of the txt file:

AAA
BBB
CCC
DDD

If I want to get a specific word (such as CCC) in the txt file, could it be possible for me to do so in xocde 4? If yes, how to program? Thank you so much

Comment: what language are you writing this in?

Answer (score 0):

xcode has nothing to do with this. Write your code in whatever language you are confident with.

I did suggest use a hashmap or dictionary or hashtable for storing the words as keys. This way querying for the words would be lightning quick....